# How can i reduce load on browser?

Tags: mysql, caching, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-2.0

I am using multiple databases on cloud and css framework twitter bootstrap  to grab the suggession on textfield using "typeahead" with ajax.
 now on every keyup event one ajax call get fire and fires a query as below:

```
public function prod_identifier_typeahead($value) {             
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('incident_mgmt');
    $list = $db->rawQuery('select id, identifier from products where identifier like "'.$value.'%";');      
    $options = array();
    while ($row = $db->fetchRow()) { 
        $options[] = array('id' => $row["products"]["id"],'name' => $row["products"]["identifier"]);                    
    }       
    $this->set('options', $options);
    $this->set('_serialize', 'options');        

}
```

Every ajax call uses the connection object .Now, Can anyone help me  to reduce load on this ajax call query processing ?

Comment: Why on earth are you using 'rawQuery' and skip using a 'Model'? This way you're *not* making use of the CakePHP framework at all. To make things even worse, `$value` will *not* be sanitized/escaped at all. **Your code is therefore very insecure and open for SQL injection** please read (at least) this chapter in the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: I know its not following cakePHPs rules...but i have multiple databases and thy are integrated with each other it makes cakephpRUN heavy and to fetch data of another database instead of default i have to use this rawQuey ...no other options i have ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Cake has [caching](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#caching) which can be used to store data that has been retrieved from the database.  Thus duplicate requests will not hit the database, however, you need to be careful that you don't fill your cache with data that will never be used again.

I would try to optimize for common usage patterns.  For example, a user types 'abdc', hits backspace twice, then types 'cd'.  In this case, you'll get a cache hit on 'ab' and 'abd' almost immediately but 5 minutes later its probably safe to clear everything associated with this query.

Comment: so...my approach is appropriate or should i replace by creating one extra cache file on every first load of the site and should use that file to grab data in typeahead..please guide me which solution i should prefer ?

Comment: If its working, I would leave it as is.  When you start to have performance issues you can look at the data and choose a caching strategy.

Comment: right nw my tables dont have huge data so its working fine ...but i am thinking that if in future data of the tables get increased it will create load on every keyup and even it will take time to create connections and fetching so can you please explain me how i should apply caching approach by default cakephp's functionalities